# Database list of objects as property of class

Tags: c#

I have a class `box` which contains few properties, one is a counter for an id that increments every time a new object is initialized and the other property is a `List<Item>` that contains many object of type `Item`, that is another class with its own properties (name, weight etc..).
I'm trying to build a database for this application, but I really don't know how to represent my `List<Item>` property in my database.
I'm a beginner, especially in databases within c#, so please be as clear as possible.

EDIT

Item.cs

```
class Item
{
    private string name;
    private int price;
    private int weight;

    public Item() { }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }

    public int Weight
    {
        get { return weight; }
        set { weight = value; }
    }

    public int Price
    {
        get { return price; }
        set { price = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show the code for the `Item` class?

Comment: Can one Item be linked to more than one box?

Comment: Yes, it can be present in multiple boxes.

Comment: What is your definition for a "database" ? For example you could serialize an instance of your object as a JSON and save that JSON to a postgreSQL (SQL) or MongoDb (NoSQL) database.

Comment: Replies are assuming that you are talking about an RDBMS. You didn't tell about that detail, and also even with RDBMS your issue could be modeled with JSON or XML datatype too. It looks like you are after something like a "Cart" and "Items" added to it, which is modeled differently based on the specific "database" you want to persist it.

Comment: Yes, it's like cart and items.

Comment: You also need to decide your "database". SQL, NoSQL. And within those groups which one, document, graph, rdf ... With RDBMS and traditional ways, one easy way to get a database built for you, is to create a 'Code first' model and then let the entity framework create a database for you.
A typical cart and items model need 3+ tables, Cart: CartID, detailFields. CartItems: ItemId, CartID, Items : ItemId, details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a `Box` has a collection of `Item` objects, then your database would have two tables for this:

```
Boxes
----------
ID
Name
etc.

Items
----------
ID
BoxID
Name
etc.
```

Things like `Name` and `etc.` would be the properties which describe any given instance of that type.  The `ID` values are the unique identifiers for the items.  The main thing to notice here is the `BoxID` column in `Items`.  For any given `Item` there is a reference to the `Box` which contains it.

So when you save a `Box` object to the database, first you would save the object itself and then, given its `ID`, save all of the `Item` objects.

This is called a "one to many" relationship.  "One" `Box` has "many" (zero or more, in this case) `Item`s.

---

**Edit:** Based on your comment below, do you mean that this would be a *many-to-many* relationship?  If that's the case then you'd need a table to hold the relationship itself.  Something like this:

```
Boxes
----------
ID
Name
etc.

Items
----------
ID
Name
etc.

BoxItems
----------
BoxID
ItemID
```

Any `Box` can relate to many `Item`s and any `Item` can relate to many `Box`es.  Consider that the relationship *itself* is an "entity" in the model.

To help visualize this, a very common example is Movies and Actors.  One can have a collection of Movies and a collection of Actors, and they clearly relate.  But *the relationship itself* is an entity with its own describing elements.  The relationship links to a Movie, and links to an Actor, but also contains information like "Character Name" or "Contract Salary".

**Note:** This approach doesn't really seem to make sense, at least semantically, for your domain.  How can one `Item` simultaneously exist in multiple `Box`es?

Comment: I know concept of primary key, foreign key and also relationships. The problem here is that I would like to use more items for more boxes and it would be many to many relationship.

Comment: You cannot have a many to many relationship in a relational database without an intermediary table.

Comment: I know, this is my problem. I need a link table. But what I should put in this table.

Comment: @Koosshh56: I've updated the answer.  If you're looking for a many-to-many relationship then you need to add a table to hold the relationship itself.

Comment: Can now this kind of database hold multiple items in one box?

Comment: @Koosshh56: Both of these approaches can hold multiple items in one box.  The many-to-many relationship doesn't seem to make sense here because that implies that one item can simultaneously be in multiple boxes.  If all you need is for any given `Box` to have a list of `Item`s then the first approach, the one-to-many relationship, does exactly that.

Comment: @David As Cetin said, it's like Cart and Items relationship.

Comment: @Koosshh56: In that case some renaming would clarify things.  Instead of `Box` and `Item`, you would have things like `Order` and `Product`.  The linking table could be `OrderProduct` or, more semantically, something like `LineItem`.  An `Order` doesn't *contain* `Product`s, but it does *reference* them.  And that reference (the linking table) would contain information about the relationship itself.  "Quantity" would be a good example.

Comment: Ok, it's really what I had in mind. Sorry for being so unclear. For the linkng table that hold the foreign Keys and quantity, do I have to create another class or just leave everything like this?

Comment: @Koosshh56: Since you're talking about a more complex domain than just "items in a box" then I would personally recommend creating classes for them.  Where else would you store things like "quantity"?  (Though if your business logic doesn't require that, you might not need it.)  Consider again the semantics that an `Order` doesn't *contain* `Product`s.  It does, however, contain `LineItem`s.  Those, in turn, have a reference to a `Product`.

Comment: So do I have to create a class `LineItem`? With which properties?

Comment: @Koosshh56: I can't really define your entire object domain for you.  Given the description so far, you seem to have three entities.  A Product, and Order, and a Line Item.  Product and Order are aggregate roots, they exist independently of one another.  LineItem exists only as a child of an Order and contains a reference to a Product.  That's pretty much the extent of what's been described at this point.

Comment: Do you think I could use a sintetic key for ID insead of using an int that increments in my class?

Comment: @Koosshh56: An auto-incrementing ID from the database is usually the simplest approach unless there's a compelling reason to use something else.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you will need at least two tables, one for boxes and one for items. If one item can belong to more than one box as well as one box having many items you will need an intermediary table (see below):

[image]

In the container tables you should have:

1. ContainerID
2. FK_BoxID
3. FK_ItemID
4. etc...

In the Boxes tables you will need:

1. BoxID
2. [box related fields]

In the Items table you will need:

1. ItemID
2. [Item related fields]

Comment: Why "at least" 2? At least 1 is fine.

Comment: In fact you need at least 3 for a proper relationship between the two in a relational database.

Comment: Ok, so I have to use an ID for Item as well. And the link table is using boxId and itemId as foreign key. This is really clear, thanks

Comment: Where did you reason he was talking about an RDBMS? Even so there are RDBMS that can do this in a single table. Based on your assumption and traditional ways of modeling this, you are not really wrong.

Comment: 'I'm a beginner, especially in databases within c#' - It was a fair assumption that he wants an RDB. Yes you can design a database to use as few tables as possible however this doesn't achieve much good in his situation.

Comment: OK. I don't know why beginner's are assumed to be after an RDBMS when they don't have an idea on the databases. My suggestion to them is to learn about databases before they try a 'database' based application.

Comment: @CetinBasoz What's your preferred database design?

Comment: For a situation like temporary Cart I prefer single table approach (be it a table in a RDBMS or a collection in a NoSQL document store). JSON is a typical sample.

Comment: I see, do you find the benefits of only using a single table outweigh the ease of use of a relational design?

Comment: Yes, "ease" is a relative term and managing a single row is easier for managing joins with multiple rows in one of them. If you have 100,000 carts with 10 items average then it means 100,000  +  1,000,000 rows in one system and only 100,000 in the other.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95728/discussion-between-cetin-basoz-and-ryan-searle).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a one-to-many relationship your classes would look like this:

```
public class Box
{
    public Box() { }

    public int BoxId { get; set; }
    public string BoxName { get; set; }

    public virtual Item Item { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public Item()
    {
        Boxes = new List<Box>();
    }
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Box> Boxes { get; set; }
}
```

Follow the article below, it also explains how to create foreign keys and everything.

http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx